# Is it possible to return reactive value to main server?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I try to filter dataset based on dates chosen by user in datepicker. The code below reflects how it works in my real app. I have a reactive dataset created in main server. I need to pass filtered dataset all the way down to all modules in my app. Actually, user picks a date in `mod_datepicker`, then I pass his choice to main server `server` where I filter dataset and then pass it to `mod_table`. I found it difficult to pass reactive value `pickedDates` to main server. The error I got is:

> Error in dates$pickedDates : couldn't find object 'dates'

Seems I can't pass reactive value `pickedDates` to main server. Is there any way to do make it possible?

Here is the reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets)


moduleServer <- function(id, module) {
    callModule(module, id)
}

# UI - datepicker #
mod_datepicker_UI <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    
    tagList(
        airDatepickerInput(
            inputId = ns("datepicker"),
            range = TRUE,
            label = 'choose date range:',
            separator = "  |  ",
            value = c(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()),
            autoClose = TRUE,
            dateFormat = 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    ))
}

# Server - datepicker #
mod_datepicker_server <- function(id){
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {

        return(
            list(
                pickedDates = reactive({input$datepicker})
            )
        )
    })
}

# UI - table #
mod_table_UI <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)

    tableOutput(ns("myTable"))

}

# Server - table #
mod_table_server <- function(id, df){
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
        ns <- session$ns

    output$myTable <- renderTable(df)

    })
}



# App - main UI and Server #
ui <- fluidPage(

    tagList(
        mod_datepicker_UI("airDatepicker"),
        mod_table_UI("table")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    Name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina")
    Date <- c('2021-07-12', '2021-07-13', '2021-07-14', '2021-07-15', '2021-07-16')
    df <- data.frame(Name, Date)
    df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
    
    # dateFrom <- reactive({ as.Date('2021-07-12') })  # if you uncomment those 2 then it works 
    # dateTo <- reactive({ as.Date('2021-07-14') })
    dateFrom <- reactive({ as.Date(dates$pickedDates[1]) })
    dateTo <- reactive({ as.Date(dates$pickedDates[2]) })
    
    # I use this reactive df in main server as to spread out data to the rest of modules in my app
    finalDf <- reactive({
        df %>% 
        filter(between(Date, dateFrom(), dateTo()))
    })

    
    dates <- mod_datepicker_server("airDatepicker")
    mod_table_server("table", finalDf())

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As an example you can ucomment `dateFrom` and `dateTo` to see it works on hard coded reactive values.

Comment: I think the solution for this is to create a `reactive` within your server function, to use as an argument for your module.  Then your module needs to be setup to change that reactive.

Comment: Ok, but I created `reactive ` in my server function: `dateFrom` and `dateTo`. I store user's choice there (`dates$pickedDates`). Then I pass those dates to reactive `finalDf` and then do `mod_table`. And it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood. `dates` is a reactive so it needs to be called like `dates()$pickedDates`. You don't actually need to re-wrap it in another reactive.

Comment: I moved `dates <- mod_datepicker_server("airDatepicker")` to the top of my server function. But when I call it like `dates()$pickedDates` it again throws error: `Error in dates$pickedDates : couldn't find object 'dates'`. The issue is - how to pass reactive value to parent module and use it in this parent module. This is the case in my example.